# Populating A Page with XML and Javascript/Jquery, checking if the url is the same as an xml tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, if-statement, auto-populate

I need to create a javascript function that will write a page based on the url, so basically I am trying to create a javascript function that will check the url, and find the corresponding xml item from there.

The reason behind this is so that the html page can just be duplicated, renamed, and the xml updated, and the page will fill in everything else from the xml sheet.

please let me know whether this is the completely incorrect way to do it, of it there is a better way. thanks!!!

XML CODE::

```
<!--XML INFORMATION-->      
<channel>
<design>
<motion><!--design content-->

<item><!--//////////POST//////////POST//////////POST//////////-->
    <tag>/portfolio_dec.html</tag>

<!--RSS INFORMATION-->      
    <title>Decoze</title>
    <link>http://payamrajabi.com/portfoliotest.html</link>
    <description><img src="http://payamrajabi.com/thumbs/small_jump.png" title="JUMP!." /></description>

<!--PROJECT CONTENT-->

<project><!--project start-->

    <titl>TITLE</titl><!--project title-->
    <dsc>PROJECT DESCRIPTION</dsc><!--project description-->

</project><!--project end-->

</item><!--//////////END//////////END//////////END//////////-->

</motion>
</design>   
</channel>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "code/content9.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

    var xpathname = window.location.pathname;
    var xproject = $(xml).find('tag').text();

    if (xpathname == xproject) {

        $(xml).find('item').children('tag').text(xpathname).each(function(){
            var ttl = $(this).find('titl').text();
            $('<p>'+ttl+'</p>').appendTo('h1#ttl');
        });

        $(xml).find('item').children('tag').text(xpathname).each(function(){
            var dsc = $(this).find('dsc').text();
            $('<p>'+dsc+'</p>').appendTo('h1#ttl');
        });                 

    } else {
        PUT ERROR MESSAGE HERE
    }
    }
    });                 
});
```

and THE HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="code/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code/project/project_design.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<h1 id="ttl"></h1>
<p id="dsc"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would really be appreciated, i am frairly new to javascript/jquery/xml, and am really having trouble with this. The primary thing I want to do is have an xml file that populates a site, with each item being the content for a new page, in this case of a portfolio item.

cheers!

willem

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... I'm afraid you don't quite understand how jquery works.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var xpathname = window.location.pathname; 

var xitem = $(xml).find('tag:contains(' + xpathname + ')').parent(); 

if (xproject.length != 0) { 
  $('#ttl').append('<p>' + xitem.find('titl').text() + '</p>'); 
  $('#dsc').append('<p>' + xitem.find('dsc').text() + '</p>'); 
} 
else {
  $('#err').text('The page you requested does not exist'); 
}
```

### Demo 1

Here's a quick demo. Take a look at the source to see the XML and the JavaScript.

http://jsbin.com/ujiho#itemOne

http://jsbin.com/ujiho#itemTwo

http://jsbin.com/ujiho#itemThree

### Demo 2

I've created another demo that uses `$.get` to retrieve the XML from a separate URL.

http://jsbin.com/aqefo#nov

http://jsbin.com/aqefo#dec

The XML: http://jsbin.com/afiwa

Here's the JavaScript. Let me know if you need help understanding anything.

```
$(function(){
  $.get(
    'http://jsbin.com/afiwa',
    function(xml){

      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

      if ($.trim(hash) === '') {
        showError();
        return;
      }

      var xitem = $(xml).find('urlname:contains(' + hash + ')').parent();

      if (xitem.length != 0) {
        $('#ttl').append(xitem.find('titl').text());
        $('#dsc').append( xitem.find('dsc').text());
      }
      else {
        showError();
      }


      function showError() {
        $('#err').text('The page you requested does not exist');
      }
    }
  );
});
```